# Nestjs schema definition with mongoose: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I am using Mongoose in a NestJS app, and I have an error when I define my schemas like those code.

Why i have an error if i set the ref in Collaboration schema like this

```
ref: Page.name,
```

but no error if i set like this ?

```
ref: 'Page',
```

**Note:** All schema definitions are in the same directory *'schemas'*.

This is my Page schema looks like

```js
    // Path: src/page/schemas/page.schema.ts

    import { Collaborator } from './collaborator.schema';

    @Schema({ timestamps: true, versionKey: false })
    export class Page {
      @Prop({ required: true, type: Number })
      owner_id: number;

      @Prop({ required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength: 100, trim: true })
      name: string;

      @Prop({ minlength: 3, maxlength: 250, trim: true })
      description: string;

      @Prop({
        type: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: Collaborator.name,
            autopopulate: true,
          },
        ],
      })
      collaborators: Collaborator[];
    }

    export const PageSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Page);
```

This is my Collaborator schema looks like

```js
    // Path: src/page/schemas/collaborator.schema.ts

    import { Page } from './page.schema';

    export type CollaboratorDocument = HydratedDocument<Collaborator>;

    @Schema({ versionKey: false })
    export class Collaborator {
      @Prop({
        require: true,
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        // there is an error if i set the ref like this
        ref: Page.name,
        /**
        but no error if i set like this
        ref: 'Page',
        */
      })
      page_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

      @Prop({ required: true, type: Number })
      user_id: number;

      @Prop({ type: String, enum: ROLES, default: ROLES.MODERATOR })
      role: string;
    }

    export const CollaboratorSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Collaborator);
```

The error in the console:

```
/src/page/schemas/page.schema.ts:42
    ref: Collaborator.name,
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that `Page` and `Collaborator` are circular with each other, and each of their imports cannot be fully resolved until the other one has (yay circular imports). You should be able to overcome this by setting the `ref` to `ref: () => Page.name` or `ref: () => Collaborator.name` so that it's a lazy evaluation of the type

Comment: I follow your solution and a have this error: ```throw new Error(`Unsupported syntax: Class constructor "${refClassName}" cannot be invoked without 'new'. Make sure to wrap your class reference in an arrow function (for example, "ref: () => ${refClassName}").`);```



```Error: Unsupported syntax: Class constructor "ref" cannot be invoked without 'new'. Make sure to wrap your class reference in an arrow function (for example, "ref: () => ref").```

Comment: That looks like you may have done `ref: () => Page` without the`.name`. Not completely sure though without seeing the current code. You can update your question with the attempt so it can be formatted better